# Dependency injection errors change with navigation flow (lazy loaded Angular modules)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am using `@angular ^4.0.1` in a Webpack AoT setup, utilizing lazy loaded modules heavily. But I am starting to see dependency injection errors that I can't find the source of. Basically, the dependencies work fine in some navigation flows, but not in others.

Here is a specific example:

`App` component lazy loads `Level1` through

```
{path: 'level1', loadChildren: './+level1#Level1Module'},
```

and in the same route style, `Level1` pulls `Level2`, which pulls `Level3`.

Those are basic components, and in this context mostly serves HTML templating.

`Level3` is where things go wrong, since I have a simple `Level3Service` declared in `Level3Module`'s providers:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Level3Component,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    Level3Service,
  ]
})
export class Level3Module {
  public static routes = routes;
}
```

Now, `Level3` has two lazy loaded children, `Level3ChildA` and `Level3ChildB`. The children routes look a little different, since they don't have any children themselves, they are actual pages:

```
{path: '', component: Level3ChildXComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

also i am NOT redeclaring the `Level3Service`, although I will be needing it. As per my understanding, if I redeclare the provider, it will no longer be a shared instance, but a new instance.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Level3ChildXComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule,
  ],
  providers: [
      // Level3Service, // Let's not redeclare this, we want a shared instance.
      Level3ChildXSomeService,
  ]
})
export class Level3ChildXModule {
  public static routes = routes;
}
```

Starting in `Level3ChildA`, the user interacts with a form, bla bla, and then I want to move the user from **A** to **B**, `Level3ChildB`. I do this from the `Level3ChildAComponent`:

```
this.level3Service.doSomething();
return this.router.navigate(['../B'], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
```

This is where the journey ends with an error and one of those crazy long stacktraces.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Level3Service!
Error
at injectionError (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:2579:86) [angular]
at noProviderError (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:2617:12) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:4118:19) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:4157:25) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:4089:25) [angular]
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:3958:21) [angular]
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:4905:52) [angular]
at Level3ChildBModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:4905:52) [angular]
(...) hundred lines omitted.
```

I am hoping someone can help me understand what is going on here.

It seems the general rule is, if I reload the app from the beginning, all the dependency providers work. But if I open a new browser, navigating directly to one of the subpages (e.g. the **A** page), then it don't know about the provider from the parent module `Level3`.

**UPDATE**

I found that this error stops to reproduce when I remove the providers array from the child module, `Level3ChildBModule`. Those were some seemingly unrelated providers, but it is as if they override the stack of providers from parent modules in some cases!

Comment: Are you using angular cli? Can you share minimal example to reproduce it? Does it behave the same in different browsers?

Comment: @yurzui I am testing using `webpack-dev-server`. I experience the same behavior in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I will look into creating a minimal sample, although I don't know if Plunkr can contain it - would a public Github repo work?

Comment: Github repo would be good example

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/TCAg6ZXTZ8qYvwUzPs9v/

Comment: @yurzui Your Plunker is pure Angular, the problem must be somewhere in the Webpack / AoT compilation. I will try to build a basic Webpack / AoT-enabled application to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes i know. I am waiting for your github repo

Comment: It appears the problem is isolated to child modules that have their own list of providers. Those seem to override parent modules' providers, as if they don't exist. Still not re-produceable in Plunker, but I updated your Plunker anyway with more detail: https://embed.plnkr.co/3WCB0X1No4MHq66wCiV7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can seemingly be resolved by updating the angular packages from `^4.0.1` to `^4.0.2`.

Could be the compiler bugfix (#15583).
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md